# How to find number of repetions of num k in Pythagorean table n*n?

Tags: algorithm

How to find the number of repetitions of the number `k` in the Pythagorean table of size `n*n`?

What would you advise?
`(1 ≤  ≤ 10^5; 1 ≤  ≤ 10^9)`

For example the input is: `6 12`

Output: `4` (Red color on the pic)

Input: `6 6`

Output: `4` (Green color on the pic)

[image]

**Note** If you search through an array, it will take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up an algorithm (the recipe you will follow to program), for this case there are two possibilities I can think of:

> Either you run through the list and look how many times you find the number, or you ask yourself why the number would appear in the list and go on from there.

Once you have set up your algorithm, you can start implementing it.

As you state correctly: using an array of size square(10^5) might not be a good idea, so this causes the first possibility to be a bad one. Then I'd advise you to use the second approach.